# Orthogonality condition for spherical harmonics

Tags: electrostatics, spherical-harmonics

The 3ed of Jackson E&M states the following as the orthogonality relationship for the spherical harmonics:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\text{sin}\theta d\theta \space Y^*_{l'm'}Y_{lm}=\delta_{l'l'}\delta_{m'm'}.$$

Is it right that the sin$\theta$ in this relationship comes from performing a change of variables on the legendre polynomial term in the spherical harmonics (i.e. changing the variable from x, which the legendre polynomials are generally written in, to cos$\theta$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it comes from the change of variables. You may be more familiar with a similar 3D computation, going from cartesian to spherical coordinates.

If you integrate over a domain $D$, start with the expression in cartesian coordinates:
$$I=\int_D\dots dx\,dy,dz$$
As you want to move to spherical coordinates, you need to compute the Jacobian of the change of variables:
$$I=\int_D\dots J\,dr\,d\theta\,d\varphi$$
with
$$J=\left\lvert\frac{D(x,y,z)}{D(r,\theta,\varphi)}\right\rvert=r^2\,sin(\theta)$$

Now if the integral is purely angular, the $r$-dependent part isn't present, and you're left with $\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\varphi$.